# cakephp 3.8 How to send data from view to controller which has index function using POST

Tags: jquery-mobile, openssl, php-7.2

Cannot send data from view to a controller using post method.

Create a cakephp 3.8 system on windows 10. The system use jquery mobile extensively. Use edge browser and "post" method. Send data from a view page to a controller page. Controller page has an index function. Data can be found in controller.
Tried the same on chrome browser. Use the "post" method. Cannot find data in controller.

What I tried to solve the issue:
I suspect that chrome browser need SSL certificate to use "post" method.
Created a SSL Certificate on Apache server. Installed the SSL certificate on client's computer. Then tried on windows 10. Worked OK but not on chrome browser.

In chrome if I use "Inspect" after I sent data on view page I can see the 
sent data after opening body tag. But not in page source.

## In view page

```
<?=$this->Form->create
    (null,['name' => 'frm','url' => ['controller' => 'Messageboard', 'action' 
    => 'index']]
    ) ?>

    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND"/>

    <?=$this->Form->end() ?>
```

## In controller page

```
    if($_POST['submit'] == 'submit'){
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    echo "Hear".$name;
    }
```

Expected result:
Send name David from view.
Hear David

Actual result:
Send name David from view.
Hear

Answer (score 0):

You can use the request handler to spesifically handle ajax requests, if that is needed, like so:

```
if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
    $data = $this->request->getData();
}
```

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/request-handling.html

You are using modelless forms. Since you aren't binding it to an entity, you need to handle all validation yourself. Read more about that here: 
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/form.html